# Responding to resize events in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is what I've tried:

```
if (jQuery(document).width() < 1024) {
    jQuery('.anywhere_div').insertAfter('#a_fixed_position_div');
}
```

I don't know how to write the `else` because I take a `div` which is placed randomly on the page and I position it under a fixed `div`.

I don't know where to put it back if I resize the window again.

Also how can I add a timer like this http://alvarotrigo.com/blog/firing-resize-event-only-once-when-resizing-is-finished/ so it wont use much resources.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: where you want to put it back!! Relevant html code if you have might help!!

Comment: > Also how can i add a timer like this

Create a separate question.

Comment: The html code doesnt help, there is nothing fixed about it, i want to take it from a sidebar and it can be anywhere , up, down, in the middle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can use as below:

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/qc4p7qrh/2/)** and **[FULL SCREEN DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/qc4p7qrh/2/embedded/result/)**

**HTML**

```
<div id="a_fixed_position_div">
    Fixed Div
</div>

<div class='originalPlace'>
    Original Place
    <div class='anywhere_div'>AnyWhere Div</div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(window).on('resize',function(){
if ($(window).width() < 1024) {
    jQuery('.anywhere_div').detach().insertAfter('#a_fixed_position_div');
}
else
{
    jQuery(".anywhere_div").detach().appendTo('.originalPlace')
}
});
```

`.detach()` detaches it from original place and moves it in place DOM positioning.

**UPDATE**

To take it from random place -

```
var originalPlace=$('.anywhere_div').parent();
$(window).on('resize',function(){
    if ($(window).width() < 1024) {
        jQuery('.anywhere_div').insertAfter('#a_fixed_position_div');
    }
    else
    {
        jQuery(".anywhere_div").detach().appendTo(originalPlace);
    }
});
```

**UPDATE 2**

Here we are saving it's `previous` and `next` element too and if it has any it will insert accordingly otherwise it will append it to its `parent` and hope this is what you need:

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/qc4p7qrh/6/)** and **[WORKING DEMO FULL RESULT](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/qc4p7qrh/6/embedded/result/)**

**HTML**

```
<div id="a_fixed_position_div">
    Fixed Div
</div>

<div class='originalPlace'>
    Original Place
    <div class="firstElem">Prev Div</div>
    <div class='anywhere_div'>AnyWhere Div</div>   
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var originalPlace=$('.anywhere_div').parent();
var previousElement=$('.anywhere_div').prev();
var preLength=$('.anywhere_div').prev().length;
var nextElement=$('.anywhere_div').next();
var nextLen=$('.anywhere_div').next().length;

$(document).ready(function(){
    checkresize();
    $(window).on('resize',function(){
        checkresize();
    });
});
function checkresize()
{
    if ($(window).width() < 1024) {
        jQuery('.anywhere_div').insertAfter('#a_fixed_position_div');
    }
    else
    {
        if(preLength!=0)
             jQuery(".anywhere_div").detach().insertAfter(originalPlace.find(previousElement));
        else
            if(nextLen!=0)
                 jQuery(".anywhere_div").detach().insertBefore(originalPlace.find(nextElement));
            else
                jQuery(".anywhere_div").detach().appendTo(originalPlace);
    }
}
```

Comment: He's asking for the possibility to move a div that can be anywhere in page,  your solution instead force it to be under .originalPlace

Comment: @SharpEdge If you have seen my solution properly then you would have come to know that he can append it back anywhere in the else part!! Its upto OP where to put it back. he just wanted how to do it?? remove it from that fixed place and put it back!!

Comment: "I take a div which is placed randomly on the page" Now you understand? Each time the page loads the div could be anywhere!

Comment: @SharpEdge.. My bad... Missed that part!! Is it ok now??

Comment: I tought to do it like this BUT e.g. if .anywhere_div is the third son of an element you lose the correct position when you put it back!
That's why i adopted a solution where you put a placeholder (i know it's not so good)

Comment: Thank you so much Guruprasad. It works BUT it has some issues.

Comment: First, the anywhere_div it doesnt show if i load the page directly to a size less than 1024, it goes where it supose to only if i resize.

Comment: Second, when i resize it back it doesn't go exactly from where it was initially. Its close but its not good. Thank you

Comment: @Kal-El.. Ok.. Here you go!! Check the update.. It solves the issue you mentioned!! **`pageload`** and **`putting back to same position`**

Comment: It's perfect! Thank you so much for this!

Comment: Anytime.. :) Happy Coding.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you've posted this is a working snippet

```js
$(function(){
  
  var resizeId;
  var size="big";
  var $placeholder = $("<!-- myElement -->");
  $(window).resize(function() {
      clearTimeout(resizeId);
      resizeId = setTimeout(doneResizing, 500);
  });
 
 
  function doneResizing(){
    
    if ($(document).width() < 1024 && size=="big") {
      
      size="small";
      
      $('.anywhere_div')
        .before($placeholder)
        .insertAfter('#a_fixed_position_div');
      
    } else if(size=="small") {
      
      size="big";
      
      $placeholder
        .after( $('.anywhere_div') )
        .remove( );
      
    }
  }

  doneResizing();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="a_fixed_position_div" style="height:100px; width:100px;"></div>
<div id="another_fixed_position_div" style="height:100px; width:100px;">
  <div class="anywhere_div" style="height:100px; width:100px; background-color:#ff0000;"></div>
</div>
```